# vs-liveserver presents different result than opening index manualy

Tags: css

Visual code live server extension presents my page perfect but if I open `index.html` manually it has lot of problems that are not shown on live server.

I searched Google but didn't find anything.
[Here](https://mega.nz/#F!MZFRFSIA!xp_j8gi4Ct9VUPwIQ2qMKg)  are the files.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what problems does the index.html file shown?  when I look at it from my side - I do not see anything that I would consider a problem. Can you show the screen shot of the problem?

Comment: sure.
this is what i see when i open with live server https://gyazo.com/7db32631d2f281e89906d534c72b591a 
and this is what i see when i open manualy
https://gyazo.com/1c3399fd95c679f72232318725ce8fc1

Comment: not sure why this is getting downvoted,started learning 3 days ago and new to the forum ,tell me whats wrong instead...

Comment: I got it to my work on my side - look at my answer and try it. The way your image paths are referenced makes all these differences. Hope this works for you too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

1. Moved both of the images to css folder
2. In the style.css file : change the paths of the images for both of their selectors:
   like this:

```
#showcase{
    background-image: url('./showcase.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 600px;

}

    .imginfo{
float: left;
min-height: 100%;
width: 50%;
background: url(./photo-1.jpg);
```